# Java open stream from an arbitrary location in file

Tags: java, filestreams

I want to get a Stream from some arbitrary position in an existing file, for example I need to read/write from/to a file starting with 101th byte.
Is it safe to use something like that?

```
final FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
fin.skip(100);
```

[Skip javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) tells that it may sometimes skip lesser number of bytes than specified. 
What should I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
final RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, mode);
raf.seek(100);
final FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(raf.getFD());
// read from fin
```

Answer (score 3):

you can't write using a FileInputStream.  you need to use a RandomAccessFile if you want to write to arbitrary locations in a file.  <strike>eunfortunately, there is no easy way to use a RandomAccessFile as an InputStream/OutputStream</strike> (looks like @aix may have a good suggestion for adapting RandomAccessFile to InputStream/OutputStream), but there are various example adapters available online.

another alternative is to use a FileChannel.  you can set the position of the FileChannel directly, then use the Channels utility methods to get InputStream/OutputStream adapters on top of the Channel.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the direction of RandomAccessFile. Eventually RandomAccessFile was all I needed, but @aix has given the exact answer I've been looking for.